# HTTP Status 404 - Using Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404

I'm doing a project where i need to make a java web project using apache tomcat.

And i start the initial configuration using the following guide:

- http://www.javainstance.com/2016/10/creating-first-web-application-using.html

But everytime i run using apache tomcat 7, i receive the HTTP Status 404 (i have a smiliar url like in that guide : http://localhost:8080/AutomatizationWebService/). And in the console it says that tomcat is up

I already saw other stack's page where i should add/remove server, clean, change the server's lcoation radiobutton, switch location but nothing seems to work

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WebService</groupId>
  <artifactId>AutomatizationPackage</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
    <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
   <build>
    <finalName>AutomatizationWebService</finalName>
      <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>AutomatizationWebService</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Thank you, for your time

Answer (score 0):

From what you have said it looks like your server is running fine but its having trouble locating the file that your looking for.

Also in the example you were looking at it runs localhost:8080/Sampleweb not localhost:8080/automizationwebservice

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and deployed application from this http://www.javainstance.com/2016/10/creating-first-web-application-using.html site and it works if you add a configuration.

If you created exactly the same project from that link , all you need is javax.servlet dependency in your pom.xml because *.jsp file are trying to find javax.servlet.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope it helps.